# git diff of file does not complain if file path is incorrect

Tags: git, git-diff

I know in git I can get a [git diff](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) of a file by doing:

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
```

In my example:

```
git diff commit1 commit2 -- dirThatDoesNotExist\myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt
```

If the path (myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt) is a file that does not exist, I don't seem to get an error or any other indication from git, just no response.

Getting an empty response is indistinguishable from no changes/differences in a valid file.

How can I get an error message indicating that the file path is incorrect, or some other way to distinguish between bad file name and no changes/differences in a valid filename?

Comment: You get no output? I get `fatal: ambiguous argument 'myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: You are right, I am using Windows if I do: git diff HEAD..HEAD^^ test.bat, and test.bat does not exist, I get "fatal: ambiguous argument", but, if I have a path not, just a file name like this: "git diff HEAD..HEAD^^ aDirThatDoesNotExist\test.bat", then I get no output. But If I switch the direction of the slash in the path, I get the unknown path error. So I guess that is the solution. Will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could test if a file exists in a commit by `git rev-parse commit:path`.

```
git rev-parse commit1:myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt
```

If `myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt` exists in `commit1`, the command returns its blob sha1 value with exit code 0. If it does not, `commit1:myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt` is returned literally with exit code 128, and an error message is put in the standard error, saying that `fatal: Path 'myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt' does not exist in 'commit1'`

```
if git rev-parse commit1:myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt || git rev-parse commit2:myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt;then
    # exist in one of the two commits or in both
    git diff commit1 commit2 -- myFileThatDoesNotExist.txt
else
    # exist in neither, do something else
    :
fi
```